# Distribute Swift App In-house

Tags: ios, swift, in-house-distribution

I have 2 applications one in Objective-C and one in swift using Xcode 6.
Both are different application which has different aspect.

I try to distribute both apps in-house using Enterprise Certificate and Profile via Cisco Meraki.

Objective-C app successfully distribute, but Swift fails.

Even though my iPad can successfully download swift app from meraki but once it finishes installing it shows "Unable to Download App" - `App Name` could not be installed at this time.

So does Apple prevent us from distribute swift app even for in-house?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: iOS7 is an operating system; Swift is a programming language.  No reason a single app can't be *both*.

Comment: there are different apps.

Comment: You do know XCode6, and Swift for that matter, are in beta, right?

Comment: yeah but that's why i want to know that is it also apply that we cannot distribute in-house. I do know that Swift is not allowed on App Store for now but what about in-house?

Comment: This question may be better directed at Meraki's support - but it sure sounds like a compatibility issue that Cisco are yet to implement in their MDM solution.

Comment: I've not used Meraki, but I have done Enterprise distribution with other tools. I've found that configuration can be quite finicky and the resulting error messages are usually not helpful. I would very thoroughly re-check your configuration for the Swift app.

Comment: What is the error when you install this Swift app? Did you install in Organizer or iTunes?

Comment: the Xcode6 is still _beta_... and the _Swift_ is still a concept language, and is not ready for commercial development. bear in mind that.

Comment: I assume you used Xcode Archive and Export as oppose to CI.

Comment: Yes I use Build Archive and Orginizer to export .ipa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that we can get around it. This helped me out, build the Swift app, use following command to archive (replace capital names with your variables):

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "APP_NAME.app" \
-o "PATH/APP_NAME.ipa" \
--sign "SIGNING_IDENTITY" \
--embed "PROVISIONING_PROFILE"
```

Comment: Nice! Works for me too. Although, weirdly enough, worked for me by excluding the --embed param as well. Bug?

Comment: @dezinezync, that is good question, I am having the same issue. I would assume that the provisioning profile dependency is cached by xcrun.

Comment: Scratch my previous comment, the provisioning profile is not injected in ipa package if excludes --embed. But the script runs fine. The provisioning profile might already be built into .app file.